# Centos yum shows different latest versions

Tags: centos, webserver, yum

i have two servers running centos, they are located in the same Data Center

i want to update my mod-pagespeed module

Server 1:

```
[root@web2 11]# yum update mod-pagespeed
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, fastestmirror, priorities, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.linuxwerk.com
 * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
 * extras: mirror.softaculous.com
 * updates: centosmirror.netcup.net
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mod-pagespeed-beta.x86_64 0:1.7.30.4-3847 will be updated
---> Package mod-pagespeed-beta.x86_64 0:1.9.32.2-4321 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                             Arch                                    Version                                        Repository                                      Size
=================================================================================================================================================================================================
Updating:
 mod-pagespeed-beta                                  x86_64                                  1.9.32.2-4321                                  mod-pagespeed                                  5.8 M

Transaction Summary
=================================================================================================================================================================================================
Upgrade       1 Package(s)
```

Server 2

```
[root@web ~]# yum update mod-pagespeed
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, fastestmirror, priorities, security
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/metalink                                            |  26 kB     00:00     
 * base: ftp.plusline.de
 * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
 * extras: ftp.plusline.de
 * updates: ftp.plusline.de
10gen                                                    |  951 B     00:00     
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
cr                                                       | 3.3 kB     00:00     
dag                                                      | 1.9 kB     00:00     
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
mod-pagespeed                                            |  951 B     00:00     
rbel5                                                    | 1.9 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00     
varnish-3.0                                              |  951 B     00:00     
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mod-pagespeed-stable.x86_64 0:1.7.30.4-3847 will be updated
---> Package mod-pagespeed-stable.x86_64 0:1.8.31.5-4307 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package                  Arch       Version            Repository         Size
================================================================================
Updating:
 mod-pagespeed-stable     x86_64     1.8.31.5-4307      mod-pagespeed     5.4 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Upgrade       1 Package(s)
```

so you see server2 says the latest version is 1.8.* server 1 says 1.9.* is

they differ in base, epel, extras mirrors,

how can i load the same version on server2 ?

Comment: Asking this both here and on serverfault at the same time isn't exactly friendly.

Comment: sorry i try to find out which one is the better place for the next time

Comment: I don't know what the official network stance on this is but it splits the answers and potentially doubles the work done to solve it. I would say at least indicate that you've done this but I'm not sure that's not actually worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod-pagespeed-beta and mod-pagespeed-stable are not the same package. Install whichever of those you want on both servers and you will likely have the same version. Assuming the mirrors are both up-to-date as you were told on the version of this question you posted to [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/652125/centos-yum-different-versions).